# Correcting the set in my proof.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

The question was:

Find $\int_{[0, \pi/2]} f$ if  $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      \sin{x}, & if  \cos(x) \in \mathbb{Q}, \\
      \sin^2{x}, &  if \cos(x) \not\in \mathbb{Q}.
   \end{cases}$$

**My answer was:**

Assume that $0 \leq x \leq \pi/2$, then taking the cosine of this, we get $\cos 0 \geq \cos x \geq \cos (\pi/2),$ so, $1 \geq \cos (x) \geq 0$ (because $\cos (x)$ is a decreasing function in this interval.)\

Now, by monotonicity of measure $$m\{x \in [0, \pi/2] \mid \cos(x)\in \mathbb Q\} \subseteq m\{[0, \pi/2] \cap  \mathbb{Q}\}.$$

But,$m\{[0, \pi/2] \cap  \mathbb{Q}\} = 0.$\

This is because $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and hence its measure is 0 and $\{[0, \pi/2] \cap  \mathbb{Q}\} \subset \mathbb{Q}$, then by monotonicity of measure $m\{[0, \pi/2] \cap  \mathbb{Q}\} = 0.$\

And since the integral of  each integrable function $f$ on a set of measure equal to $0$ is $0$, we have:\

$\int_{[0, \pi/2]} f = \int_{[0, \pi/2] \cap  \mathbb{Q}} f + \int_{[0, \pi/2] \cap  \mathbb{Q}^c} f = 0 + \int_{[0, \pi/2] \cap  \mathbb{Q}^c} f = \int_{[0, \pi/2] \cap  \mathbb{Q}^c}  \sin^2{x}  = \int_{[0, \pi/2] \cap  \mathbb{Q}}  \sin^2{x} + \int_{[0, \pi/2] \cap  \mathbb{Q}^c}  \sin^2{x} dx = \int_{[0, \pi/2]}  \sin^2{x} dx,$\

Where in the last equality we have changed the Lebesgue integral over  $[0, \pi/2]$ into Riemann integral over $[0, \pi/2]$ because our function $\sin^2{x}$ is Riemann integrable and bounded by $[0,1]$ and the domain of integration is closed and bounded interval then by \textbf{ Theorem 3, on page 73} the Lebesgue integral is the Riemann integral.\

Now we can compute this integral:\

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}f(x)\,\mathrm d x=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2(x)\,\mathrm d x = \int_0^{\pi/2} \{ \frac{1 - \cos{2x}}{2} \} d x = \frac{\pi}{4} - ( \frac{1}{4} \times 0) = \frac{\pi}{4}. $$

**But it turns out that:**

My justification in this step:

$$m\{x \in [0, \pi/2] \mid \cos(x)\in \mathbb Q\} \subseteq m\{[0, \pi/2] \cap  \mathbb{Q}\}.$$ was wrong, could anyone help me correct this step please?

Comment: If $X=\{x\in [0,\pi/2]\mid \cos(x) \in\Bbb{Q}\} $ then since $\cos(x) $ is bijective on $[0,\pi/2]$ then there is a bijection between $X$ and $[0,1]\cap \Bbb{Q}$ ($f(x) =\cos(x) $) so $X$ is countable so it's measure is $0$. If I understood correctly that you only needed the measure to be $0$.

Comment: yes this is exactly what I need. what do you mean by $\mathbb{Q}(f(x) = \cos (x))$?

Comment: I meant we take $f(x) =\cos x$ it's easy to prove that function is a bijection on $X\to \Bbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$. Probably should have written it more clearly.

Comment: Could you please write your detailed answer as an answer so that I can accept it? @kingW3

Comment: Also, could you please look at this question for me (if you do not mind) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388757/proving-some-points-missed-in-my-proof?

Comment: for my first comment above my question is:  do you mean the rational numbers that satisfy $(f(x) = \cos (x))$ ?@kingW3

Comment: Let me rewrite that part; then there is a bijection between $X$ and $[0,1]\cap \Bbb{Q} $(we can take $f(x) =\cos (x) as an easy bijective function.). As for the other question I'm not really good at measure theory so someone else might be better suited to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to directly prove that $X=\{x\in [0,\pi/2]\mid \cos(x) \in\Bbb{Q}\}$ is countable.

There is a natural bijection between $X\to \Bbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ given by $f(x) = \cos(x) $ since $\cos$ is injective (1 on 1) on $[0,\pi/2]$ then so it is on $X\subseteq [0,\pi/2]$.

Since $\cos x$ is surjective (onto) from $[0,\pi/2]$ to $[0,1]$ then for each element from $[0,1]\cap\Bbb{Q}$ there is a corresponding element $y\in [0,\pi/2]$ such that $\cos y=x$ but by definition $\cos y=x\in\Bbb{Q} $ so $y\in X$.

Comment: I don't think we need to know that $\cos$ is onto. All we need is that $c^{-1}(y)$ is finite for any $y$, where $c$ is $\cos$ restricted to $[0, \pi / 2]$. Then $X = c^{-1}(\Bbb{Q} \cap [0, 1])$ is clearly countable.

Comment: Could you please explain your idea in detail in an answer @HewWolff?

Comment: why "all we need that $c^{-1}(y)$ is finite for any $y$"?@HewWolff

Comment: I think it's because then there is a finite $M$ such that $|c^{-1}(y)|\leq M$ then $|c^{-1}(\Bbb{Q}\cap [0,1])|\leq |M||\Bbb{Q}\cap [0,1]| =|\Bbb{Q}\cap [0,1]|$. Though it's better if HewWolff answers what he thinks; anyway a different way with avoiding onto is that $X\to \Bbb{Q}$ is an injection so $|X|\leq |\Bbb{Q}|$ which means that $X$ is countable, or we could take $X\to \Bbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ and we'd still get $|X|\leq |\Bbb{Q}\cap [0,1]|$

Comment: in the last line in your answer, when you said "by definition" which definition do you mean? @kingW3

Comment: @Smart by the definition of $X$

Comment: why $|X| \leq |Q|$ means that $X$ is countable? do you mean finite countable or infinite countable? and so by this, it will still have measure 0? can not it be an interval?

Comment: @Smart it doesn't matter whether it is finite/infinite countable, any countable set has measure $0$. Because the cardinality of $X$ is smaller or equal to the cardinality of $\Bbb{Q}$ which is countable. It can't be an interval because no interval has measure $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding a little on my comment...We need to show that we can ignore the $\cos x \in \Bbb{Q}$ case and just integrate $\sin^2$. Moreover, this is true when integrating over any subset $J \subseteq \Bbb{R}$, not just $J = [0, \pi/2]$.

I claim that $X = \{x \in J: \cos x \in \Bbb{Q} \}$ is countable. If this is true, then $X$ has measure zero, and deleting that case in the definition of $f$ does not change the integral of $f$, as required.

We can assume $J = \Bbb{R}$ since this gives us the largest $X$. Note that for any $y \in \Bbb{R}$, if we define $C_y$ as $\{x \in \Bbb{R}: \cos x = y\}$, then $C_y$ is countable (look at the way horizontal lines meet the cosine graph). $X$ is just $\bigcup_{y \in \Bbb{Q}} C_y$, so it's a countable union of countable sets. So $X$ is countable, as required.

Comment: it seems a very nice idea :)